# How to start drawing printDocument from Right to Left in C# WInforms ?

Tags: c#, winforms-interop

[image]

How to start drawing from right to left ? 
الرقم التسلسلي should appear in the right

Comment: Can you see if this thread is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124738/printing-right-to-left-in-c-sharp

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.alignment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
    p.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
    p.Print();
}

static void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    string drawString = "إختبار الرسم";
    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    Font drawFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arail", 16);
    RectangleF recAtZero = new RectangleF(0, 0, e.PageBounds.Width, 
    e.PageBounds.Height);
    StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();

    drawFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;

    e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, recAtZero, 
    drawFormat);
    RectangleF recAtGreaterThantZero = new RectangleF(300, 0, 
    e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, 
    recAtGreaterThantZero, drawFormat);
}
```